# How to connect to Alexa with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, http, http2, alexa-voice-service

I'm writing an Qt application and try to use Alexa API. I received access token, but I can't use API because of `"Host  not found"` and `"Connection closed"`.

My `QNetworkAccessManager` defined as

```
amazonHelper.data()->setNetworkAccessManager(view.data()->engine()->networkAccessManager());

...

void AmazonHelper::setNetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager *qnam) {
    qDebug() << "setNetworkAccessManager()";
    _manager = qnam;
    connect(_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}
```

After executing

```
_manager->connectToHostEncrypted("https://avs-alexa-na.amazon.com");
```

I receive an error `"Host  not found"`.

After executing

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://avs-alexa-na.amazon.com/v20160207/directives"));
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer %1" + _accessToken.toUtf8());
_manager->get(request);
```

I receive an error `"Connection closed"`.

What is a right way to use Amazon Alexa API?

Thanks in advance!

**UPD1:**
I found `QNetworkRequest::SpdyAllowedAttribute` in Qt documentation but when I tried to set this attribute I got the follow error: `'SpdyAllowedAttribute' is not a member of 'QNetworkRequest'`

**UPD2:**
I tried to use `libcurlcpp` but after setting `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` to `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0` got exception (https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp/issues/84)